# Why do I get a value out of range: underflow and how do I work around it?

Tags: sql, postgresql, underflow

Is it possible to avoid `value out of range: underflow` with casting the values to some types explicitly?

The function that causes the exception is:

```
create or replace function produciblepwforregulation(now date, timerange integer, devicename character varying) returns void
    language plpgsql
as $$
BEGIN
    FOR t IN 1..timeRange BY 1
        LOOP
            BEGIN
            insert into values
            (value, time, devicename)
            values (    2200 +
                        600 *
                                round(abs(sin(((t) * 0.042))) + 0.1) *
                                (sin(sin(((t) * 2 / 2.0 / 2.155172413793103 * PI()))) /
                                abs(sin(sin(((t) * 2 / 2.0 / 2.155172413793103 * PI()))))) *
                                (3 - exp(-12.5 + floor((t) * 2 / 2.0 / 2.155172413793103) * 2.155172413793103 * PI() * 2 * round(abs(sin(((t) * 0.042))) + 0.1) - ((t) * 2 * PI())))
                        +
                        600 *
                                abs(round(abs(sin(((t) * 0.042))) + 0.1) - 1) *
                                (sin(sin(((t) / 2.0 / 4.310344827586207 * PI()))) /
                                abs(sin(sin(((t) / 2.0 / 4.310344827586207 * PI()))))) *
                                (3 - exp(-25.5 + floor((t) / 2.0 / 4.310344827586207) * 4.310344827586207 * PI() * 2 * abs(round(abs(sin(((t) * 0.042))) + 0.1) - 1) - ((t) * PI())))
                        + 50 * sin(3 + (t) * 0.092) + 350 * sin(3 + (t) * 0.012),
                    now + t * INTERVAL '1 second' - 1 * INTERVAL '1 milliseconds',
                    devicename);
              END;
        END LOOP;
END

$$;
```

What kind of data types produce the underflow during the calculation?